# Удаление тегов из строки в perl

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Имеется строка

```
$phrase= "Some br text br br without br";
```

Необходимо удалить все `br` в этой строке и получить строку

```
$phrase= "Some text without";
```

Как лучше это  сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$phrase =~ s/br//g;
```

Есть более интересная "регулярка", она вырезает ВСЕ HTML теги из текста.

```
s/<(?:[^>'"]*|(['"]).*?\1)*>//gs
```

**UPD:** [[@Anton Shevtsov](/users/3274/anton-shevtsov)](/users/3274/anton-shevtsov) верно подметил, необходимо задать границы слова, чтобы не повредить нормальные слова.

$phrase =~ s/\bbr\b//g;

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо!

Comment: не то.. т.к. при 
    $phrase="Some br text br br without br. My brother" у вас от brother останется other.. надо вот так $phrase =~ s/\bbr\b//g;

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -E '$p="Some br text br br without br"; $p =~ s/br//g; $p =~ s/\s+/ /g; say $p'
```